# HTML Comment-out Add-In

Tags: visual-studio-2010, add-in

[Here](http://www.vbrad.com/article.aspx?id=29) is an old add in to quickly comment out HTML code. Maybe I am missing it, but it seems like there is a shortcut in VS2010 to scratch your tail with one click but commenting out HTML code is still awkward as hell.

What's the easiest way to get a function like this working?

Can I expect any add-ins that were written for older versions of VS to work in VS2010 w/o an upgrade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio's Comment Selection command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>) works with HTML.

You can also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>U</kbd> to uncomment.

Comment: Cool. What's the easiest way to add a menu option or preferably a toolbar button to equate to this key sequence?

Comment: Show the Text Editor toolbar, or click Edit, Advanced.